# How do the new moderator queue buttons impact flag weight?

Tags: discussion, flag-weight, moderator-tools

The dismiss as **valid** or **invalid** links have been replaced with buttons.  I can guess that the buttons to close, convert to comment, and delete a post have a positive effect on the flaggers flag weight.  Can we assume that the "no action needed" button will always subtract 10 points from flag weight?

The reason I ask is that a question that's already closed only has the "delete" and "no action needed" buttons.  The question was flagged *before* it was closed, but I no longer have the option to just close the question or dismiss the flag as valid.  I can only delete the question or dismiss the flag with "no action needed."

Comment: We're actually having a chat about this in the Lounge, so feel free to pop in. ♪

Comment: I will add a "..." to make it clear that there is a popup

Comment: Thanks @Marc, that should clear up any confusion.

Comment: @Marc: Also, can you un-banninate me from the Teachers' Lounge?  I got kicked yesterday, I *hope* by accident.  Thanks.

Comment: @Bill - you didn't get a memo, then? ;p Just kidding... looking now

Comment: My chat profile parent site somehow got set to Area 51.  Switching it back to SO fixed the problem.

Comment: never assume that it will subtract 10 forthwith

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clicking on the "no action needed" gives a dialog that has two options "valid" and "invalid":

[image: dismiss flags]
<sub>(source: [mrozekma.com](http://so.mrozekma.com/dismiss-flag.png))</sub>

The descriptions say it all I think.

(I got caught out by this as well).

*(Thanks to Michael Mrozek for supplying the screenshot)*

Comment: Thanks.  I was too paralyzed by fear to actually click the button and see what happened.  :)

Comment: @Bill - I was too ;)

Answer (score 3):

Clicking "no action needed" actually brings up two more options, which may seem familiar: valid and invalid. My assumption is that those will then adjust the flag weight just as before.